# For facet_wrap function in ggplot2, is there a way to store each subset plot independently?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(whole_data,aes(x=x1,y=x2)+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 80, vjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~x3,nrow=3)
```

Since if the plots are together, there will be some axes
problem.

For example, the numbers on y-axes will all overlap;

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. And honestly, if you want to save each facet, or in better words, if you want to apply the same graph for each subset of your data, and save each of these graphs in a different image archive, I think you actually need a loop like below. I can be wrong, but I think this is what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
levels_x3 <- unique(whole_data$x3)

plot_model <- function(level){
  
  select_data <- whole_data %>% 
    filter(x3 == level)
  
  plot <- ggplot(
    select_data,
    aes(x=x1,y=x2)
    ) +
    geom_point()+
    theme(
      axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 80,
        vjust = 0.5
        )
    )

  print(plot)
}


map(
    levels_x3,
    function(x){
      png(paste("image_", x))
      plot_model(x)
      dev.off()
    }
  )
```